# email's contains = symbol is replaced with some characters in gmail/outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, gmail

I am sending automated mail which is in html format. I am providing a link in the mail which point towards url with equal(=) symbol. for eg: **http://mail.com?hello=10_world**
this url is replaced with **http://mail.com?hello%10_world**, that is =symbol is replaced with % symbol in gmail/outlook.

Am i missing some thing???

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe the URL in your email is being URL encoded. Try to play around with the URLEncode() or URLDecode() method in c#. I'm not putting this as an answer because it's a mere guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email is using quoted-printable, so the code `=10` represents the character with character code 10, i.e. Line Feed (LF). When the line feed character is found in the URL, it has to be URL encoded to make a link out of it, so it's encoded using the sequence `%10`.

So, it's not the `=` that is replaced by `%`, it's the `=10` that is decoded as `LF` and then encoded as `%10`.

To put a `=` character in quoted printable you need to escape it as `=3D`.

Comment: now i am encoding that url using HttpUtility.UrlEncode, now its working fine.. but don't know whether something else would break this or not.